# Sort rows in a 2d array in a descending direction by comparing a column of float values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, usort

When I try to apply the below code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2/2699159#2699159)

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
});
```

it gives me results in ascending order.

**Output**:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0.29
1.09
6.33
```

On swapping $a and $b it gives the results in descending order except one value

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['order'] - $a['order'];
});
```

**Output**:

```
6.33
1.09
0
0
0
0
0.29
0
```

i want to have the results in the below order:

```
6.33
1.09
0.29
0
0
0
0
0
```

How do i achieve the same.?

Comment: By swapping "a" and "b". Something else is wrong here.

Comment: that something i am unable to find..

Comment: maybe some of the elements are stored as strings. Try casting to some numeric type.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

My first guess is that usort expects an integer response, and will round off your return values if they are not integers. In the case of 0.29, when it is compared to 0, the result is 0.29 (or -0.29), which rounds off to 0. For usort, 0 means the two values are equal.

Try something like this instead:

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['order']==$b['order']) return 0;
    return $a['order'] < $b['order']?1:-1;
});
```

(I think that's the correct direction. To reverse the order, change the `<` to `>`)

Comment: PHP needs a `signum()` function. BASIC had this function over 40 years ago.

Answer (score 21):

using the space ship operator in php 7 (and over):

```php
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] <=> $b['order'];
});
```

would return the array sorted in ascending order. reversing the comparison will return it in descending.

```php
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['order'] <=> $a['order'];
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Just switch the $a and $b around as follows;

```
function sort($a, $b){ 
return strcasecmp($b->order, $a->order);
}
usort($myArray, "sort");
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but hopefully this helps someone. Easiest way to set descending order, is to just multiply by negative one (-1) as shown below. Worked well for me, with text.

```
function DESC($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["text"], $b["text"])*-1;
}

usort($results,"DESC");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also simply reverse the array once it has been sorted.

Starting the same way you did:

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
});
```

and then reversing the results like this:

```
$myArray = array_reverse($myArray);
```